# Change color middle visible row

Tags: uitableview

I create a subview for create a custom pickerview, I use a tableview item for do it, I need to have a different color only for the middle cell, for example if I have 3 visible row I need to have grey,black,grey, for do it I try in this way:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells];
    for (int i = 0; i < [visibleCells count]; i++) {

        if (i == 1) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:i];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

the first time tableview appear is good but if I scroll I get first 2 or last 2 cell of one color and the remaining cell have the other color. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: ok.. do you want a quick answer... or an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells];
    for (int i = 0; i < [visibleCells count]; i++) {

        if (i == 1) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:i];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
        else{
            UITableViewCell *cell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:i];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

When you scroll a tableview.. the rows that are not visible are 'deleted' and 'recreated' when shown.. thats why there is a reuse identifier.. to reuse those cells.. if you reuse a cell with blackColor.. AS YOU DONT HAVE AN ELSE STATEMENT..  it will remain black.. even if you wanted it gray.. add the else statement to get the desired result.. GL HF

Comment: if you want this gray, black, gray pattern to continue.. change this --> if(i==1) for  this --> if(i%2==1)